# insert query inside for loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm currently working on a form that generate fields.

My problem is when I tried to insert to the database, it was successful, however the only data that is being inserted is the last fields.

I tried to just echo the result and it is working fine.

I even try to use foreach but it has the same result.

I hope you can help me.

**CODE**

```
require_once 'inc.connection.php';

$shipping_code = generateRandomString();
$packaging = $_POST['packaging']; 
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$total_weight = $_POST['total_weight'];
$length = $_POST['length'];
$width = $_POST['width'];
$height = $_POST['height'];
$unit = $_POST['unit'];
$freight_class = $_POST['freight_class'];



$counter_count = count($packaging);

for($a=0; $a < $counter_count; $a++)
{


    $sql = "INSERT INTO shipping_items (user_id, shipping_code, packaging, quantity, total_weight, length, width, height, unit, freight_class)
    VALUES ('$_SESSION[id]', '$shipping_code', '$packaging[$a]', '$quantity[$a]', '$total_weight[$a]', '$length[$a]', '$width[$a]', '$height[$a]', '$unit[$a]', '$freight_class[$a]')";


}
```

Comment: you have written the query but not executed it

Comment: `however the only data that is being inserted is the last fields.`? i didn't see any insert query execution code

Comment: is it entering repeatedly or just a single row

Comment: just a single row sir

Comment: Well pointed out coder, You need to execute it each time within the loop, each time this runs $sql is being over written so when you execute the sql after your for loop it only has the last iteration of the loop that it can enter.

Comment: my best guess is that, you have put your `mysqli_query()` outside the `for` loop.. that is why only the last query was saved in the database. Solution was of course, put your `query` function inside the loop.

Comment: ether you use bulk insert using `$sql[]` or execute the statement in `foreach`

Comment: wouldnt turning $sql into an array require another loop to execute the queries?

Comment: it working now sir.. Thank you for your help, catzilla is correct and coder also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the statement : mysql_query($sql) inside the loop... it will solve your problem

Comment: @misdirection  also if you just started then please stop using `mysql_*` (deprecated and removed library). Switch over to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` along with `prepared statements`

Comment: The question was tagged with mysqli and there is no query execution in the code sample supplied to suggest otherwise.

Comment: its working now sir.. I tried what catzilla and pAsh suggested